# How scala orders tuples?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to understand how scala handles ordering and sorting of tuples

For example, if I got the list

```
val l = for {i <- 1 to 5} yield (-i,i*2)
Vector((-1,2), (-2,4), (-3,6), (-4,8), (-5,10))
```

scala knows how to sort it:

```
l.sorted
Vector((-5,10), (-4,8), (-3,6), (-2,4), (-1,2))
```

But tuple don't have a '<' method:

```
l.sortWith(_ < _)

error: value < is not a member of (Int, Int)
l.sortWith(_ < _)
```

How does scala know how to sort those tuples?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because `sorted` have an implicit parameter `ord`:

> def sorted[B >: A](implicit ord: math.Ordering[B]): List[A]   Sorts
>   this sequence according to an Ordering.
>
> The sort is stable. That is, elements that are equal (as determined by
>   lt) appear in the same order in the sorted sequence as in the
>   original.
>
> **ord** the ordering to be used to compare elements.

and there is an implicit conversion defined in `scala.math.Ordering`:

```
implicit def Tuple2[T1, T2](implicit ord1: Ordering[T1], 
                                     ord2: Ordering[T2]): Ordering[(T1, T2)]
```

So `l.sorted` will be transformed to `l.sorted(scala.math.Ordering.Tuple2[Int, Int]())`.

Test it:

```
scala> def catchOrd[A](xs: A)(implicit ord: math.Ordering[A]) = ord
catchOrd: [A](xs: A)(implicit ord: scala.math.Ordering[A])scala.math.Ordering[A]

scala> catchOrd((1,2))
res1: scala.math.Ordering[(Int, Int)] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$11@11bbdc80
```

And of course, you can defined your own `Ordering`:

```
scala> implicit object IntTupleOrd extends math.Ordering[(Int, Int)] {
     |   def compare(x: (Int, Int), y: (Int, Int)): Int = {
     |     println(s"Hi, I am here with x: $x, y: $y")
     |     val a = x._1*x._2
     |     val b = y._1*y._2
     |     if(a > b) 1 else if(a < b) -1 else 0
     |   }
     | }
defined object IntTupleOrd

scala> Seq((1, 10), (3, 4),  (2, 3)).sorted
Hi, I am here with x: (1,10), y: (3,4)
Hi, I am here with x: (3,4), y: (2,3)
Hi, I am here with x: (1,10), y: (2,3)
res2: Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((2,3), (1,10), (3,4))
```

**EDIT** There is a short way to make `Tuple[Int, Int]` support all the following methods: `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`.

```
scala> implicit def mkOps[A](x: A)(implicit ord: math.Ordering[A]): ord.Ops =
     |   ord.mkOrderingOps(x)
mkOps: [A](x: A)(implicit ord: scala.math.Ordering[A])ord.Ops

scala> (1, 2) < (3, 4)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> (1, 2) <= (3, 4)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> (1, 2, 3) <= (1, 2, 4)
res2: Boolean = true

scala> (3, 3, 3, 3) >= (3, 3, 3, 4)
res3: Boolean = false
```

Comment: I don't know. Sorting tuples can sometimes lead to confusing results.
`(100L, 2D) :: (2L, 5001D) :: Nil sorted`
gives:
`List((2,5001.0), (100,2.0))`. It looks like there's no weightage on the second element of the tuple.

Comment: Ordering looks at the second element of the tuple only when the first elements are equal.

Answer (score 4):

@Eastsun's answer nicely explains the first part of your question "how does Scala sort tuples".

Regarding the second part "why doesn't tuple have a `<` method": In Scala, comparators like `<` either translate to native JVM comparisons for basic types (when comparing `Int` or `Double` etc) or to member functions of `someClass` with the type `<(that: someClass): Boolean`. This case is actually just syntactic sugar: `someObject < otherObject` translates to `someObject.<(otherObject)`. If you want to have this functionality for tuples, you can bring an implicit class into scope, and map the comparison member function to the comparators provided by the `Ordering`:

```
implicit class ProvideComparator[T](t1: T)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]) {
  def <(t2: T) = ord.lt(t1, t2)
  def >(t2: T) = ord.gt(t1, t2) // and so on
}
```

Now you can just write:

```
scala> (1,2) < (2,2)
res2: Boolean = true
```